# Horizontal lines of table has different length

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the problem that I got different `\hline` lengths for one table. The source code is listed below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\def\btc{\begin{tabular}{c}}
\def\etc{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Trimming Summary}
\label{tab:trimming}
\vspace{0.5em}
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{r|ccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{1em}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\scriptsize Processed Reads} \\
\cline{2-4}
 &No. Reads & \btc Base Pairs (bp)  \etc & \btc Length\\ (bp) \etc \\
 \hline
\color{violet}{SUM}&\color{violet}{1,923,313,717}&\color{violet}{203,289,006,008}&\color{violet}{106} \\
\color{red}{AVERAGE}&\color{red}{4,006,903}&\color{red}{423,518,762}&\color{red}{106}\\
\color{green}{MEDIAN}&\color{green}{3,046,151}&\color{green}{323,854,746}&\color{green}{107} \\[1pt]
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output table. As you can see, the second line is longer than others.

[image: Second line is longer than others]

Comment: Welcome, completely unrelated and off-topic: Do you really want the colored rows?

Comment: The thing you need to be aware of: You can't fit an elephant in a suitcase. You have very large numbers and have to use a very small font size in order to fit them. On the other hand, you restrict the tabular to a certain width but are not using the `X` column featured by the `tabularx` package. That leads to strange results. And i better not mention the `\btc` definition. You should never do that.

Comment: Everything works fine with a _regular_ `tabular` environment, and as noted by Johannes, you don't use any extensible column that could allow LaTeX to properly achieve the desired width for your `tabularx`. Test with `{X|ccc}` columns for instance, now it works.

Comment: Thank all of you for invaluable help. And I also appreciate your honest suggestion on table format itself.

Answer (score 5):

You *must* use at least an `X` column, if you want that `tabularx` is effective.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,array}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Trimming Summary}
\label{tab:trimming}
\medskip

\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  |
  *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  @{}
}
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\scriptsize \strut Processed Reads} \\
\cline{2-4}
&No. Reads & \splitcell{Base Pairs \\ (bp)} & \splitcell{Length \\ (bp)} \\
\hline
\textcolor{violet}{SUM}&\textcolor{violet}{1,923,313,717}&\textcolor{violet}{203,289,006,008}&\textcolor{violet}{106} \\
\textcolor{red}{AVERAGE}&\textcolor{red}{4,006,903}&\textcolor{red}{423,518,762}&\textcolor{red}{106}\\
\textcolor{green}{MEDIAN}&\textcolor{green}{3,046,151}&\textcolor{green}{323,854,746}&\textcolor{green}{107} \\[1pt]
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\color{red}{x}` is the wrong syntax (unfortunately, it is used by MathJax).

[image]

I'm not sure what the colors should do; in my opinion they just make it difficult to read the table.

A better realization:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Trimming Summary}
\label{tab:trimming}
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=10.0]
  S[table-format=12.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Processed Reads} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
&{No. Reads} & \splitcell{Base Pairs \\ (bp)} & \splitcell{Length \\ (bp)} \\
\midrule
SUM     & 1923313717 & 203289006008 & 106 \\
AVERAGE &    4006903 &    423518762 & 106 \\
MEDIAN  &    3046151 &    323854746 & 107 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your MWE have two errors:

- newer use `tabularx` without using its column type `X`!
- correct syntax for color text is `\textcolor{<color>}{ text }`

Considering above rules I obtain the following result (with some small changes of table design):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\def\btc{\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}}
\def\etc{\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{caption}% <-- added

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Trimming Summary}
\label{tab:trimming}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} % <-- added
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}       % <-- added
\scriptsize%\tiny               % <-- changed
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{r|
                                >{\centering\arraybackslash}X % <-- added
                                cc}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Processed Reads} \\
\cline{2-4}
    & No. Reads     & \btc Base Pairs (bp)  \etc    &   \btc Length\\ (bp) \etc \\
    \hline
\textcolor{violet}{SUM}     % <-- changed in all colored text
    &\textcolor{violet}{1,923,313,717} &\textcolor{violet}{203,289,006,008} &\textcolor{violet}{106} \\
    \hline
\textcolor{red}{AVERAGE}
    &\textcolor{red}{4,006,903}         &\textcolor{red}{423,518,762}       &\textcolor{red}{106}\\
    \hline
\textcolor{green}{MEDIAN}
    &\textcolor{green}{3,046,151}       &\textcolor{green}{323,854,746}     &\textcolor{green}{107} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I will not judge your table design, a better formatting (to my taste) you cans see in Johannes_B answers (very recommended to use it). Also I didn't guess, is number are series of numbers separated by coma or one huge number, for which is better to use `S` column type from `siunitx` package as suggested Johannes_B in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

A completely different approach with a different layout.

[image: deliniTabular]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
%\def\btc{\begin{tabular}{c}}
%   \def\etc{\end{tabular}}% Never do stuf like that!

\usepackage{showframe}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Trimming Summary}
    \label{tab:trimming}
    \tiny
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{rS[table-format=10]S[table-format=10]S[table-format=3]} 
        \toprule  
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Processed Reads} \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        & \multicolumn{1}{L}{No. Reads}     & \multicolumn{1}{L}{Base~Pairs (bp)} & \multicolumn{1}{L}{Length (bp)}  \\
        \midrule
        Sum     & 1923313717 & 203289006008 & 106  \\
        Average & 4006903    & 423518762     & 106  \\
        Median  & 3046151    & 323854746     & 107  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because of the difference between cline and hline. hline draws a horizontal line accross the whole table whereas \cline{x-y} draws a line beginning at column x and ending at column y.
If I remember correctly a column ends slightly before the end of the table and that's why they have different length.

A solution for you would be to replace all the \hline with \cline{1-4}.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\def\btc{\begin{tabular}{c}}
\def\etc{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Trimming Summary}
    \label{tab:trimming}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \tiny
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{r|ccc} 
        \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{2}{1em}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\scriptsize Processed Reads} \\
        \cline{2-4}
        &No. Reads & \btc Base Pairs (bp)  \etc & \btc Length\\ (bp) \etc \\
        \cline{1-4}
        \color{violet}{SUM}&\color{violet}{1,923,313,717}&\color{violet}{203,289,006,008}&\color{violet}{106} \\
        \color{red}{AVERAGE}&\color{red}{4,006,903}&\color{red}{423,518,762}&\color{red}{106}\\
        \color{green}{MEDIAN}&\color{green}{3,046,151}&\color{green}{323,854,746}&\color{green}{107} \\[1pt]
        \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The cause of the problem is something different. Even with your proposed solution, you'll note the table is off-centre.

Comment: Will have a deeper look into that then. Thanks for pointing that out